# join DataFrames on a partially matching index

Tags: join, pandas

I'm trying to find a more elegant way to join two `DataFrame`s where the index levels of one DF are a partial subset of the index levels of the other DF. This is a very common operation in SQL and I'm surprised to find it's so difficult to do with `pandas`:

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        2012:[4,5,8,9],
        2013:[1,2,4,7],
        2014:[6,5,4,3],
    },
    index= pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('apples',False),('bananas',False),('oranges',True),('lemons',True)], names=('fruit','citrus'))
)
```

=>

```
                2012  2013  2014
fruit   citrus                  
apples  False      4     1     6
bananas False      5     2     5
oranges True       8     4     4
lemons  True       9     7     3

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Now I want to know the highest number of each fruit sold in a given year:

```
fruit_max_by_date = df.max(axis=1).to_frame()
citrus_max_by_date = fruit_max_by_date.max(level='citrus')
citrus_max_by_date.columns = [1]
```

=>

```
fruit_max_by_date =

                    0
    fruit   citrus   
    apples  False   6
    bananas False   5
    oranges True    8
    lemons  True    9

    [4 rows x 1 columns]

citrus_max_by_date =

            1
    citrus   
    False   6
    True    9

    [2 rows x 1 columns]
```

**So far so good.** But now I try to join the latter two together:

```
fruit_max_by_date.join(citrus_max_by_date) =>

                    0   1
    fruit   citrus       
    apples  False   6 NaN
    bananas False   5 NaN
    oranges True    8 NaN
    lemons  True    9 NaN

    [4 rows x 2 columns]
```

**Argh!!** Because the index of the second table doesn't exactly match the index of the first table, the join fails. *This seems totally contrary to the intuitive behavior of an SQL-like inner join.*

All the workarounds below (especially the second) are butt-ugly and basically involve either throwing the index out the window, or manually broadcasting the index of one table. **Is there a simpler way to do this?**

## Workaround: Expand the index of the smaller table through broadcasting

This is the least-ugly workaround I could come up with, but it's still quite bad in that it requires expanding the size of the second array for no good reason.

```
fruit_max_by_date.join( 
  citrus_max_by_date.reindex(fruit_max_by_date.index, level='citrus') ) =>

                    0  1
    fruit   citrus      
    apples  False   6  6
    bananas False   5  6
    oranges True    8  9
    lemons  True    9  9

    [4 rows x 2 columns]
```

## Workaround: Truncate the index of the first table

This is horribly ugly, especially having to reassemble the index afterwards, but it works.

```
fruit_max_by_date                   \
    .reset_index(level='fruit')     \
    .join(citrus_max_by_date)       \
    .set_index('fruit',append=True  \
    .reorder_levels((1,0))          =>

                    0  1
    citrus fruit        
    False  apples   6  6
           bananas  5  6
    True   oranges  8  9
           lemons   9  9

    [4 rows x 2 columns]
```

## Drop all pretense of using an index, and join without index

Okay, this is relatively straightforward, but what exactly is the point of having an index if you can't use it?

If using `join` — but not `merge` (FML!!) — there is another bizarre side effect: the joined-`on` column is reduplicated in the output:

```
    fruit_max_by_date.reset_index().join(
       citrus_max_by_date.reset_index(),
       on='citrus', rsuffix='_' ) =>

             fruit citrus  0 citrus_  1
        0   apples  False  6   False  6
        1  bananas  False  5   False  6
        2  oranges   True  8    True  9
        3   lemons   True  9    True  9

        [4 rows x 5 columns]

    fruit_max_by_date.reset_index().merge(
       citrus_max_by_date.reset_index(),
       on='citrus' ) =>

             fruit citrus  0  1
        0   apples  False  6  6
        1  bananas  False  5  6
        2  oranges   True  8  9
        3   lemons   True  9  9

        [4 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: What version are you using?  I don't have any problem using the most recent version (0.16.2).  Possibly this was added in version 0.14.0?  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-join-on-mi

Comment: Argh... thanks. I'm on 0.13 ... shoulda upraded already :-(